# Send invoice email to custom mail address in magento

Tags: magento

I have added custom functionality to send invoice email to some other mail address(excluding customer & admin). For this I have called custom function in observers

```
<sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    <observers>
       <test>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>test/observer</class>
          <method>sentMailToothers</method>
       </test>
   </observers>
```

Observer code

```
  $template_id    =   'sales_email_invoice_template';
  $emailTemplate  =   Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
  $storeId =   Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
  $invoice =   $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();  
  $order   =   $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder();
if ($order->hasInvoices()) 
            {
                foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) 
                {
                    $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true);
                    $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();

                    $email_to = 'test@test.com';//dynamic email address
                    $customer_name = 'Test'
                    $email_template_variables = array(
                                                    'order' => $order,
                                                    'invoice' => $invoice,
                                                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
                                                    );

                    $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
                    $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sender_name);
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($sender_email);
                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);

                    echo $processedTemplate;die;
                    //Send the email!
                    $emailTemplate->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);
                }
            }
```

Everything works fine except , product information not showing in templates.

Can somebody figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this or not.

Answer (score 0):

No need this code. In magento have default functionality for sending invoice email to Bcc.

Goto Admin->System(main nav)->configuration(sub nav)->Sales emails->invoice(tab)-> field "Send Invoice Email Copy To" .

please check below screenshots.

[image]

Comment: I knew about this.But I can not pass the email address in this manner. It will send all the mail to a particular address. But I want send mail to only particular address. More ever ,the mail will send to dynamic address as par custom logic.